# Shortest way from pointers to nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way that the pointers from the callouts use the shortest possible way to the nodes? So this is somehow an optimization problem ;-)
This is my code. The callout part is copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432276/tikz-callouts-with-multiple-pointers-shadows-opacity-and-overlay/432326#432326).

```
    \documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains, shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,shadows.blur,shapes}
\tikzset{
    add path/.style = {
        decoration={show path construction,
            moveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}
            },
            lineto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            curveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath .. controls (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            closepath code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- cycle}
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
    store path/.style = {add path},
    store path/.prefix code={\xdef\savedpath{}},
    callouts/.style={
        store path,
        append after command={
            foreach \target in {#1}{
                ($(callout)!2pt!-90:\target$)--\target --($(callout)!2pt!90:\target$)
            } \savedpath
        },
        alias=callout
    },
    custom style/.style={fill=blue!20,text=},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
[baserect/.style={text width=0.5cm,align=left,draw,},
diam/.style={diamond,draw,align=left,text width=1cm,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=yellow,text=white,minimum size=2cm},
basecirc/.style={circle,draw,align=center,text width=1.5cm},
circ/.style={basecirc,fill=blue!60,text=black}]     
\node [diam] (1) {asdf};
\node [circ, right=5 of 1] (2) {asdf};
\node [diam, below=2 of 2] (3) {asdf};
\path[custom style] (3,1) node[callouts={(1.east),(2.west),(3.north west)}]{blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

***Edit:*** My question is how I can optimize the distance from the callout to where the pointers touch the nodes. In the image the green line is shorter than the red one.  How do I find the coordinate of the point of the node which is closest to the callout?
[image]

Comment: `pgfpointshapeborder` might solve part of your question. For instance the shortest path from `blah` to the blue circle is from `blah.south east` to `\pgfpointshapeborder{blue circle}{blah.south east}`. For shortest paths between rectangles, they are usually from corner to corner.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility that is not a real optimization, but can be approached is to use the `fit` library. This library creates a node that contains all the coordinates. This node is the smallest `bounding box` that contains all the coordinates. 
Once this is done, we can for example place the callout in the center of this bounding box.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains, shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,shadows.blur,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
    add path/.style = {
        decoration={show path construction,
            moveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}
            },
            lineto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            curveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath .. controls (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            closepath code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- cycle}
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
    store path/.style = {add path},
    store path/.prefix code={\xdef\savedpath{}},
    callouts/.style={
        store path,
        append after command={
            foreach \target in {#1}{
                ($(callout)!2pt!-90:\target$)--\target --($(callout)!2pt!90:\target$)
            } \savedpath
        },
        alias=callout
    },
    custom style/.style={fill=blue!20,text=},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
[baserect/.style={text width=0.5cm,align=left,draw,},
diam/.style={diamond,draw,align=left,text width=1cm,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=yellow,text=white,minimum size=2cm},
basecirc/.style={circle,draw,align=center,text width=1.5cm},
circ/.style={basecirc,fill=blue!60,text=black}]     
\node [diam] (1) {asdf};
\node [circ, right=5 of 1] (2) {asdf};
\node [diam, below=2 of 2] (3) {asdf};
\node[draw=red, fit=(1) (2) (3)](fit) {box};
\path[custom style] (fit) node[callouts={(1.east),(2.west),(3.north west)}]{blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: node-callout]

Comment: +1. `barycentric cs:` from the pgfmanual section 13.2.2 might also be a nice option.

Comment: @marmot Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking. I let you write this solution which will be more beautiful because I have to go to sleep.

Comment: No, please add it to your nice answer. There is no point in having two "competing" answers here. ;-) I will then remove my comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Apparently my question hasn't been clear enough (I'm sorry, I find it quite difficult to describe it). I hope it's clear now what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a temporary post till AndréC wakes up. You can do that rather easily using the fact that you already load the `calc` library, but this code redefines the syntax, i.e. you can no longer put brackets around the pointers.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains, shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,shadows.blur,shapes}
\tikzset{
    add path/.style = {
        decoration={show path construction,
            moveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}
            },
            lineto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            curveto code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath .. controls (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            closepath code={
                \xdef\savedpath{\savedpath -- cycle}
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
    store path/.style = {add path},
    store path/.prefix code={\xdef\savedpath{}},
    callouts/.style={
        store path,
        append after command={
            foreach \target in {#1}{
            let \p1=($(\target.center)-(callout)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)+180}
            in
                ($(callout)!2pt!-90:(\target.center)$)--(\target.\n1) --
                ($(callout)!2pt!90:(\target.center)$)
            } \savedpath
        },
        alias=callout
    },
    custom style/.style={fill=blue!20,text=},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
[baserect/.style={text width=0.5cm,align=left,draw,},
diam/.style={diamond,draw,align=left,text width=1cm,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=yellow,text=white,minimum size=2cm},
basecirc/.style={circle,draw,align=center,text width=1.5cm},
circ/.style={basecirc,fill=blue!60,text=black}]     
\node [diam] (1) {asdf};
\node [circ, right=5 of 1] (2) {asdf};
\node [diam, below=2 of 2] (3) {asdf};
\path[custom style] (3,1) node[callouts={1,2,3}]{blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks marmot! I would like to use for one callout normal coordinates. If I just replace the name of the nodes by coordinates it doesn't work. What do I have to do so I can use normal coordinates aswell?

Comment: @ESV In this version, you could just give the coordinates names with `\coordinate (X) at ...`. I am actually hoping that Symbol 1 spells out an answer using `pgfpointshapeborder`. This is the correct way to go. That's why this is only a temporary answer, and I do not want to "steal" the answer from Symbol 1 and/or AndréC.

Comment: @marmot Feel free to answer this question, I don't know enough about the `system layer` to answer this problem.

Comment: @AndréC & marmot Thank you both for your answers. The trick with the coordinates works fine for the moment. When I have more time I'll read the respective chapter in the manual and see if I understand it. Otherwise I'll just ask again ;-)